# How can I lerp a vector3 by time not by position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections;

public class LerpExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Animation-Curve")]
    public AnimationCurve slideCurve;
    public Transform finalPosition;

    private Vector3 initialPosition;
    public float time;

    private void Awake()
    {
        initialPosition = transform.position;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(MoveObject());
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        
    }

    private IEnumerator MoveObject()
    {
        float i = 0;
        float rate = 1 / time;
        while (i < 1)
        {
            i += rate * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(initialPosition, finalPosition.position, slideCurve.Evaluate(i));

            yield return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using animation curves to make the transform start decreasing speed and then when getting close to the target to decrease the speed.

but I ant now to lerp without finalPosition position but with finalPosition as time.
for example, if I will set the time to 7 so the transform will start lerp from its position, and after 7 seconds where ever the transform is reached decrease down the speed back.

The target instead position will be time.

Now it start to slow down near the target after 7 seconds or in 7 seconds for example 7 seconds but I want that it will start to slow down in 7 seconds without a vector3 target just after 7 seconds slow down and stop.

I have this situation :

An object that starts moving by force with a rigidbody on the terrain.
While the object is moving I want the player to start moving too beside the object with the rigidbody.

The player should start moving slowly to max speed than when the other moving object near stops moving the player should slowly slow down to stop.

IN general, I used the SpeedUp and SlowDown methods but they were working fine when I wanted to do it when moving the player forward. The problem is that the parameter "Forward" will move the player only in the forward direction.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Cinemachine;
using FIMSpace.FLook;

public class Rolling : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject mainCam;
    public CinemachineFreeLook freeLookCamGameplay;
    public CinemachineFreeLook freeLookCamPickUp;
    public Transform player;
    public Transform crate;
    public Transform cube;
    public Animation anim;
    public UnlockCrate unlockCrate;
    public float timeToStopRolling;
    public float speed;
    public float waitBeforeSlowdown;
    public float startDrag;
    public float endDrag = 50;
    public float rotationSpeed;
    public static bool hasStopped = false;

    private bool crateOpenOnce = false;
    private bool alreadyRolling;
    private Rigidbody rb;
    private Quaternion defaultRotation;
    private Animator animator;
    private bool startSpeedUp = true;
    public float lerpTimeMultiplicator = 0.25f;

    private float timeElapsed = 0;
    private float lerpDuration = 3f;
    private float startValue = 1;
    private float endValue = 0;
    private float valueToLerp = 0;
    private bool triggerOnce = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        defaultRotation = rb.rotation;
        animator = player.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        var distance = Vector3.Distance(crate.position, player.position);
        if (distance < 1.7f && crateOpenOnce == false && unlockCrate.HasOpened())
        {
            rb.isKinematic = false;
            crateOpenOnce = true;
        }

        if(crateOpenOnce && startSpeedUp)
        {
            StartCoroutine(SpeedUp());
            StartCoroutine(WaitBeforeSlowdown());
            
            startSpeedUp = false;
        }

        if(animator.GetFloat("Forward") == 0f && startSpeedUp == false &&
            triggerOnce == false)
        {
            
            triggerOnce = true;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator Slowdown()
    {
        while(timeElapsed < lerpDuration)
        {
            timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
            valueToLerp = Mathf.Lerp(startValue, endValue, timeElapsed / lerpDuration);
            animator.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);

            // Yield here
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator SpeedUp()
    {
        while(timeElapsed < lerpDuration)
        {
            timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
            valueToLerp = Mathf.Lerp(endValue, startValue, timeElapsed / lerpDuration);
            animator.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);

            // Yield here
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator WaitBeforeSlowdown()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(13f);

        timeElapsed = 0;
        StartCoroutine(Slowdown());
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        //NOTE: In general you should go for Tags instead of the name
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "Crate_0_0")
        {
            if (crateOpenOnce)
            {
                rb.drag = 0f;

                // Directly start a routine here (if none is already running)
                if (!alreadyRolling) StartCoroutine(RollingRoutine());
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "Crate_0_0")
        {
            

            var brain = mainCam.GetComponent<CinemachineBrain>();
            brain.m_DefaultBlend.m_Time = 1f;
            freeLookCamGameplay.enabled = false;
            freeLookCamPickUp.enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private Vector3 GetRandomDirection()
    {
        var rnd = Random.insideUnitSphere;
        rnd.y = 0;
        return rnd.normalized;
    }

    private IEnumerator RollingRoutine()
    {
        // Just in case prevent concurrent routines
        if (alreadyRolling) yield break;

        // Block new routines from starting
        alreadyRolling = true;

        // Get the random direction for this routine
        var rollDirection = GetRandomDirection();

        // Roll for the given time within the FixedUpdate call
        for (var timePassed = 0f; timePassed < timeToStopRolling; timePassed += Time.deltaTime)
        {
            // Wait until you are in FixedUpdate
            // the code after this is now executed within FixedUpdate
            yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();

            rb.AddForce(Vector3.right /*rollDirection*/ * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        // Wait before slowing down
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitBeforeSlowdown);

        // Do slow down and rotate to default until both conditions are fulfilled
        var dragLerpFactor = 0f;
        // Store the original drag to reset it later
        var defaultDrag = rb.drag;
        while (!Mathf.Approximately(rb.velocity.sqrMagnitude, 0) || rb.rotation != defaultRotation)
        {
            // Again wait until you are in FixedUpdate
            yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();

            dragLerpFactor += Time.deltaTime * lerpTimeMultiplicator;
            rb.drag = Mathf.Lerp(startDrag, endDrag, dragLerpFactor);

            rb.MoveRotation(Quaternion.RotateTowards(rb.rotation, defaultRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
        }

        // Just to be sure to end with clean value assign once
        rb.rotation = defaultRotation;
        rb.drag = defaultDrag;
        rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;

        hasStopped = true;

        Destroy(transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>());
        Destroy(transform.GetComponent<SphereCollider>());
    }
}
```

That is why I'm trying to use the code in the LerpExample script.

The main goal is to move the player slowly to max speed and then slowly to stop beside the rolling t transform in the Rolling script.

Comment: So without a final position ... where will you move to? It's a bit unclear what exactly you are asking if you don't want to give a final position .. then what will you provide? A movement requires at least a direction and velocity ....

Comment: @derHugo you're right I didn't explain enough.  The problem started here with this short question : https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/osdq2d/how_can_i_set_animator_controller_state_parameter/  because I can't change the parameter direction it will move the player forward only and I want the player to move backward that is why I'm trying to use now a animation curves.  I will update my question to clear it.